# How come the first element of an array is equal to the array ?C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

For example let's say you have an array a and a pointer p.Here it is how it goes.

```
void main() {
    int a[10];
    int *p;
    for(i = 0;i <=10;i++)
        a[i] = (i + 1) * 2;
    p = &a[0];
    printf("%d",a[4]);
    printf("%d",p[4]);
}
```

How are they equal ?

Comment: Congratulations. You have found one of the hidden knowledges of pointer arithmetics.

Comment: Note that a[0] is not the same thing as &a[0].

Comment: Note that accessing `a[10]` (inside the loop) will cause *undefined behavior*.

Comment: May I suggest to read carefully a good C book or tutorial? I think you'll gain a better understand than wrong individual interpretation.

Comment: Are you asking why the array starts at its first element? :-)

Comment: The title is utterly confusing, and the question is unclear.

Answer (score 5):

*How come the first element of an array is equal to the array  ?*. Lets say you have an integer array like `int arr[5];` then according to your question headline

- *first element of an array* will be `arr[0]` which is value of `arr[0]` and
- *array* means `arr` and `arr` names represents base address of the array. So `arr` and `arr[0]` are not same. `arr` is base address & `arr[0]` is value.

For your particular case, integer array `a` looks like below & all elements of   array are stored in consecutive memory location. Assume array base address is `0x100`(some memory location)

```
 a[0]   a[1]  a[2]  a[3]  ........................................ a[9]
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  2  |  4  |  6  |  8  |  10  |  12  |  14  |  16  |  18  |  20  | 22  |
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x100   0x104  0x108 ..                                         ..    
 a
LSB                                                                   MSB
```

So here `a` means `0x100`, by assuming base address of `a` is `0x100`. Now when you do

```
p = &a[0]; /* here you are setting p to point to one of the places in the array a and that is a[0] */
```

here `p` is pointing to `first` element of `a` i.e `0x100` as below

```
       a[0]   a[1]  a[2]  a[3]  ........................................ a[9]
      ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |  2  |  4  |  6  |  8  |  10  |  12  |  14  |  16  |  18  |  20  | 22  |
      ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    0x100   0x104  0x108  0x112 0x116..                                         ..    
     a
     |
     p
```

Now when you print `a[4]` it prints `10` which is quite simple as expected & it expands like below

```
a[4] = *(a + 4) /* here you can say that array name a is converted to a pointer to its first element */
     = *(0x100 + 4*4 ) /* multiplied by 4 ? bcz a is int array & each element size is 4 byte */
     = *(0x116) /* value at 0x116 memory location */
     = 10
```

And when you print `p[4]` it expands like below

```
p[4] = *(p + 4)
     = *(0x100 + 4*4) /*multiplied by 4 because int pointer increments by 4 bytes*/
     = *(0x116) ? /* it prints value at 0x116 location which 10 */
     = 10
```

Also while assigning values to array elements in the for `loop`, you are trying to access `a[10]` which is out of boundary & causes **undefined behavior**. In the below code block condition part should be `i<10` instead of `i<=10` as you declared `a[10]` and array index starts from `zero`.

```
for(i = 0;i <=10;i++) {  /* make it i<10 */
        a[i] = (i + 1) * 2;
}
```

Finally `void main() { /* code */ }` is bad  practice and its not according to C standards specification. Use `int main(void) {  }` instead as specified in C standard `n1256` draft.

> 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup
>
> 1 The function called at program startup is named main. The
>   implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be
>   defined with a return type of int and with no parameters:
>
> `int main(void) { /* ... */ }`
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any
>   names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are
>   declared):
>
> `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }`
>
> or equivalent;9) or in some other implementation-defined manner.

Comment: Just a small note: `0x100 + 16` would be `0x110`, and the sequence above should also be `...0x108, 0x10c, 0x110...`

Comment: OS gives different address(in hexa decinmal so I took 0x), just to explain Op I took base address of `a` as `0x100`, its not `0001 0000 0000` its just `100` i.e some address.

Comment: Yes, that wasn’t my point. It’s just that the prefix `0x` signifies hexadecimal notation, so the math in the answer doesn’t quite add up.

Answer (score 3):

[Array definition](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/): An array is a series of elements of the same type placed in contiguous memory locations that can be individually referenced by adding an index to a unique identifier.

When you take the address of the first element of the array (`&a[0]`), you will get the exact same value as `a`. (however you will lose the size information, as `&a[0]` is a pointer to the memory, where `a` is actually the array)

This is because `a[0]` actually translates to `*(a + 0)`, where `a` is the pointer to the memory address your array resides at. So `&a[0]` becomes `&(*(a + 0))` or "the address of the content of the address `a + 0`", which is the same as "the address `a`"

Similarly, `a[4]` translates to `*(a + 4)`.

I hope this clarifies things :)

EDIT:

I just found this page, where you can read more about it:
https://www.le.ac.uk/users/rjm1/cotter/page_59.htm

EDIT 2:
Clarified the difference between `&a[0]` and `a`

Comment: "This is because an array is basically a pointer (but with some size information)." - incorrect definition

Comment: `&a[0]` is not exactly the same as `a`. Just try using both expressions with `sizeof`.

Comment: @AlexLop.Can you edit the post with the correct definition? I don't know it :)

Comment: "however you will lose the size information" - what do you mean by that?

Comment: An array is absolutely not a pointer! A pointer is itself a variable holding the memory address of an object. An array is a memory region large enough to hold a string of objects of same size. The only way to access elements is through the use of the very first element address displaced by the amount of object size multiplied by its position in the array. That&#39;s why C in some cases permit to legally use base address as a pointer.

Comment: ... where `a` is converted to an expression that is a pointer to the first element of `a`.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are stored in contagious memory and &a[0] is a pointer reference to first element. Now if you want to get pointer reference to second that would be (address of first element + sizeof(int)). Now you can access it's value by *(address of first element + sizeof(int). This is called pointer arithmetic. You must refer to a good book to learn more about it.

Comment: Every pointer references a memory address. Why not just "pointer"?

Comment: You are right. It makes more sense to me. I can relate it to real life.

Answer (score 0):

You assigned pointer ‘p’ to point the local array ‘a’,
so from now on ‘p’ and ‘a’ are the same array,
every change you make to ‘p’ will influance directly on ‘a’ and vice versa.

```
p = &a[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

In a[10], a is a pointer which points to the address of first element of the array. So When you assigned:

```
p = &a[0];
```

P is also storing the same address at that of a and point to same element. So any manipulation made to p will be reflected in a.

Answer (score 0):

When you write
p=&a[0];
is the same as
p=a;
now p and a are pointers on the beginning of the same array

Comment: `a` is not a pointer, it is array. You cannot write `a = p;`. It just won't even compile.

Comment: surely,but I can write
p=a;